# Twig - applying a leading "0" in front of gallery items

Tags: html, symfony, twig

First time posting so forgive me in advance.

I'm building out an image gallery. I'm using Twig. Currently my Slick carousel gallery counter is displaying "1 / 4" items in my gallery. That's all kosher. Where I'm stumped is I'm trying to append a "0" so that the slide display reads "01/04".

Here is the HTML/Twig:

```
<div class="nav-controls">
    {% if gallery %}
        <div class="gallery-count"><span id="current-slide">1</span> / {{ gallery.images|length }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    <section role="navigation" class="gallery-arrows{% if gallery %} active{% endif %}">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="prev"></div>
            <div class="next"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Is there not a way to do this with Twig?

Thank you!

Comment: Obvious answer I know, but if it's your site and you know the gallery will never have 10 or more items, you can just manually add it : `/ 0{{ gallery.images|length }}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you fancy `printf` syntax you can use Twig's [`format`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format.html):

```
<div class="gallery-count">
  <span id="current-slide">01</span> / {{ "%02d"|format(gallery.images|length) }}
</div>
```

Comment: @sbunker you're welcome, please consider accepting my answer :)

Comment: Ah! Sorry about that. Still learning the ways of StackOverflow! :)